# how to auto enable flash while running selenium test script in chrome 64.0?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, flash, automation

how to auto enable flash while running selenium test script in chrome 64.0

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
// Enable Flash for this site
prefs.put("PluginsAllowedForUrls", "https://arlo.netgear.com");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

this code doesn't seems to be working